# Connecting to an OAuth2 protected Spring Config Server

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, cloud, keycloak, configserver

I have a Spring Cloud Config Server protected with OAuth2 through Keycloak.
On the client, there is no option to configure this flow (only basic authentication). Any solutions?

Thanks